# Onde armazenar arquivos binários nos unit tests do JUnit com Maven?

Tags: java, junit, resources

Eu tenho a seguinte estrutura de diretório para a pasta resource dos unit tests:

```
src/test/resources/*.files
```

Para que eu possa ler arquivos binarios (como um PDF por exemplo) para concluir um unit test, estou colondo estes arquivos na pasta test/resources, porém lendo a documentação do Maven, esse diretório é apropriado para arquivos que são carregados em runtime, e tais arquivos seriam chamados com `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()`.

Qual seria a melhor prática para armazenar e ler arquivos PDF que serão utilizados para testes em um ou mais unit test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O correto é colocar nesse diretório mesmo. Quando você executar o teste, os arquivos serão lidos em runtime, só que no runtime do teste. Então o que a documentação diz também está correto.

Você deve criar uma estrutura de pasta igual a estrutura da classe que será testada. Exemplo, digamos que a classe que irá ler o pdf se chama PdfReader e que ela esteja nessa hierarquia:

```
-src/main/java
    -com/example/PdfReader.java
```

O seu arquivo de teste deverá seguir a mesma hierarquia, dessa forma:

```
-src/test/resources
    -com/example/arquivo.pdf
```

A única diferença é que o diretório root da classe java é o `src/main/java` e o diretório root do arquivo de teste é o `src/test/resources`

Como o arquivo será lido fica a seu critério. Você pode usar tanto o `getClass().getResource("")` quanto o `getClass().getResourceAsStream("")`. Vai depender se você precisa de uma stream ou não.

Comment: Além do getClass().getResource(), eu posso utilizar o FileInputStream? Pq geralmente usam o getClass().getResource() e não um File, FileInputStream e similares para ler arquivo nos unit test?

Comment: Não tem problema usar o `FIleInputStream`, o que você tem que se atentar é que o seu teste unitário tem que rodar em qualquer máquina. Se você usar o `FileInputStream`, você não pode usar um path que só existe na sua máquina. O `getResource` irá procurar o arquivo na pasta resources do projeto independente de qual diretório o projeto se encontra. Se os arquivos necessários também forem comitados, qualquer um que baixar o seu projeto vai conseguir rodar os testes unitários.

Comment: O mesmo comportamento pode ser alcançado utilizado o `FIleInputStream`, porém pode dar mais trabalho porque você vai ter que montar o path na mão. O correto é colocar os arquivos na pasta resources, então não faz muito sentido não usar os métodos que já buscam os arquivos de lá.